# Cannot determine type of array parameter when its value is null

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper, npgsql

Using PostgreSQL database and Dapper.

Here's a minimal example of the failing code:

```
await using var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(_configuration.ConnectionString);

return await connection.QueryAsync<Diamond>(
  @"SELECT
      id,
      name
    FROM
      product
    WHERE
      @Names IS NULL OR name = ANY(@Names);",
  new
  {
      Names = Names,
  });
```

This works fine if `Names = new { "Tom", "Dick", "Harry" }`.

However it fails if `Names = (string[]) null`.

The error I get is:

```
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P18: could not determine data type of parameter $1
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass160_0.<<DoReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass160_0.<<DoReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.QueryAsync[T](IDbConnection cnn, Type effectiveType, CommandDefinition command) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.Async.cs:line 419
```

Is it possible to send nullable array parameters in Dapper to PostgreSQL, or do I need to find a workaround?

Comment: Quite similar problem is discussed over here (https://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?t=37803) but the postgre driver is a different one.

Comment: thank you - that linked helped solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@PeterCsala was correct. The issue was that PostgreSQL prepares the query server side, so casting the parameter in C# world doesn't help. The casting must be done in SQL world.

The working code becomes:

```
await using var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(_configuration.ConnectionString);

return await connection.QueryAsync<Diamond>(
  @"SELECT
      id,
      name
    FROM
      product
    WHERE
      @Names::text[] IS NULL OR name = ANY(@Names);",
  new
  {
      Names = Names,
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution with the community. :)